# pushbullet - The param 'file_url' has an invalid value

Tags: linux, push-notification

I'm trying to use curl to send an image to a device.
this is the code :

```
#!/bin/bash
curl --header 'Access-Token: d78sdf8bd8bv6d98bd7d6df6b' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data-binary '{"type":"file","title":"Test IMG SEND","body":"Sending Dragon from Debian 8","file_name":"dr1.jpg","file_type":"image/jpeg","file_url":"https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/HJGFC56597ggiyui78698GYGUFI7865/dr1.jpg"}' \
     --request POST \
     https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes
```

and this is what I got from the previous upload :

```
{"data":{"acl":"public-read","awsaccesskeyid":"JSUH(=Y£GhHUIOG898787","content-type":"image/jpeg","key":"HJGFC56597ggiyui78698GYGUFI7865/dr1.jpg","policy":"ecvjksdblvuio3ghuv393783230cgfgsaidfg3","signature":"hjveirvhj34veupiv34'vvg3vg78"},"file_name":"dr1.jpg","file_type":"image/jpeg","file_url":"https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/HJGFC56597ggiyui78698GYGUFI7865/dr1.jpg","upload_url":"https://upload.pushbullet.com/upload-legacy/yVayDlcd
```

To me, it seems ok, but obviously there is something wrong. Can anyone point me to a solution?

EDIT :
I'm sorry, the problem is that the answer from pushbullet is that "The param 'file_url' has an invalid value" and I'm not able to understand where is the problem, becouse I just copied the file_url from the previous answer from the upload-request, which should be -> file_url":"https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/HJGFC56597ggiyui78698GYGUFI7865/dr1.jpg    ...

Comment: Not sure what's "obviously" wrong. What's obvious to you might not be obvious to us. If it's regarding something in the JSON output, then this is not a bash question.

Comment: read your question twice, I don't know the difference between "ok" and "wrong"... :(

Comment: I'm sorry... I edited the main question...

Answer (score 1):

This error isn't clear as to what's actually invalid about the `file_url` request. What it should say is, "The file url you specified points to a file that does not yet exist". In other words you need to make sure the file is actually uploaded first before you can link to it.

Their docs aren't great. I had the same issue and finally stumbled upon the answer. This is actually a 3-part process:

1) `POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/upload-request` – It wasn't immediately obvious, but this is requesting access to upload your file to Push Bullet's AWS S3 Bucket. Use the `data` in the response for the next step.

2) `POST https://upload.pushbullet.com/upload-legacy/yVayDlcd` – (This should be the value from `upload_url` from Step 1) Everything in the `data` object should be posted along with the file to the `upload_url` in the response. The expected response should be a 204 with no content. This means it was successful.

3) `POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes` – Finally now that the file exists in Push Bullet's system you can push using the `file_url` value from Step 1.

Hopefully this explanation adds some clarity to their docs.